# Is there any way to install 2 XAMPP versions in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, xampp

Can I install 2 XAMPP versions in Ubuntu 18.04? The purpose is to manage two separate PHP versions. Normally I can do it in Windows.

I know can use **docker** for it, but I'm new to **Linux** and like use easy to manage control panel for **Ubuntu** also.

Answer (score 1):

Download the versions from their site, versions 7.1.18 and 7.2.6, extract them into `/opt/xampp/7.1.18/lampp` and `/opt/xampp/7.2.6/lampp`. You can even install a 3rd, 4th or 5th version if you want.

Create a symlink from `/opt/lampp` to  `/opt/xampp/7.2.6/` to use 7.2.6. You will need to shutdown the current running xampp and then recreate the symlink to 7.1.18 to use the older version.

If you want to use both at the same time you need to edit the configuration of 1 of the 2 to `Listen` to another port. You can then use `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:port` to use them both at the same time (that URL will open the respective XAMPP config website for that installation). You do that by editing (for the 2nd of the installations, you can do the same for a 3rd, 4th, 5th installtion):

```
/opt/*/etc/my.cnf 
/opt/*/etc/php.ini 
/opt/*/etc/httpd.conf
```

Please consider using our native LAMPP and an installation from source in /opt/ of our native LAMPP. The 2nd install is the same as above but support from AU will be a lot better than from XAMPP. Plus our version is made for production systems, XAMPP is not.

Comment: My lampp installation not looks like this, it install using run the xampp package using cli

Comment: You need to download the source install version for each of the versions and tell it to install (or unpack) into the directories similar to what I showed (I included the version number they used just for a reference).

Comment: I have followed http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-xampp-ubuntu-18-04/ tutorial.